# Identifier not found or not unique. Compilation errror

Tags: ethereum, solidity

/home/ubuntu/token_sale/contracts/SandeepDappToken.sol:17:34: DeclarationError: **Identifier not found or not unique.**
        function  transfer(address _to, **unit256  _value**) public returns (bool success)
                                        ^—–^
Compilation failed. See below
**code:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract SandeepDappToken
{
    // constructor

    // set the v ariable
    uint256  public totalSupply;

    string public name = ‘Dapp’;

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    constructor(uint256 _initialSupply )  public {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
        totalSupply = _initialSupply;
    }

    function  transfer(address _to, unit256  _value) public returns (bool success)
    {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your code:

unit256 to uint256

```
function  transfer(address _to, uint256  _value) public returns (bool success)
```

Comment: thanks so much!  I never thought I would mis-spell this `unit`